# IntelliJ services window runs the application in the run window not in its own window

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've got a few applications that I want to run at the same time and the Services view in IntelliJ is ideal for this.

In previous versions I could always launch the application and it would run them on the right hand tab and I could switch between tabs easily by choosing the application on the left hand side.

Now I've moved to 2022.1 (or maybe something else in my config), every time I launch an application from the services view it opens it in the Run view and switches the view away from the nice Services view.

Is there something I need to configure or is this a bug?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: this issue always poping out from nowhere... now in webstorm 2023.2. changing the name of the task(run/dev/build) to something else usually solve it but this is annoying

Answer (score 0):

You can add/remove run configuration types from Services as shown below:

[image: Add]

[image: Remove]

Comment: I have added them - Applications in my case. I see them in the left hand pane. The problem is that when I launch them they go off to the normal Run window and I lose the benefit of the Services View.

Comment: @Dan Do you mean they open in new tab? Make sure [this option](https://i.imgur.com/KSLs4zE.png) is disabled.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear, they open in the Run Tab not the Services Tab

Comment: I can't reproduce the described behavior in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2. Please try with the default settings (File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png) and a new project. Contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new if you need more help.

Comment: That's a bit brutal :) but ok...

Comment: Tried that and the problem still persists....

Comment: Please contact support with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also check if 2022.2 release has the same problem for you. It may be already fixed in the current release.